# What to do if we cannot leave a foreign country to go to India and get the currency exchanged?

Tags: canada, india, currency

My friend moved to Canada in July 2015.  And has money in Indian currency notes of denomination 500 and 1000. I know that people living abroad who want to exchange the currency can come to India till March and get it exchanged. But my friend can only come back after July 2017 because of the visa she has. Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to send money with someone who is going to India, he/she deposits in his account, and NEFT/IMPS you (if you have indian savings account) or to your family member, relative, or bring back the new notes in cash for you.

You could also give a copy of your ID Document, with a simple authorisation letter, and your bank details, so he could deposit directly in your account, will not work if you have NRE account.

Comment: ".. he/she deposits in his account, and NEFT/IMPS you... " This is to be avoided. There is NO Restriction of depositing with a Simple Authorization Letter.

Comment: Yeah, I was more talking about smaller amounts, like I have 1000*3, 500*5, and the friend going to india is from far state, and I am not in hurry, so, if he succeeds with auth letter, fine..

Answer (score 0):

There are no further clarifications. Hopefully in few weeks time Govt may allow more avenues.

Your friend can also send this via someone along with authorisation letter